# Laravel 5 & Summernote - Uploaded image not showing up

Tags: php, laravel, summernote

I'm trying to install summernote on my website built upon Laravel 5.  However, no matter what I do, I cannot make an uploaded image file show up on an editor.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
});
$('#summernote').summernote({
    height: 400,
    onImageUpload: function(files) {
        data = new FormData();
        data.append("image", files[0]);
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: "POST",
            url: "/image/upload",
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(url) {
                console.log(url);
                // trying to make the image show up here...
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And this is php code and it works.

```
public function upload_image(ImageRequest $request)
{
    if($request->hasFile('image')){
        $filename = str_random(20).'_'.$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $image_path = base_path() . '/public/images/thread/';
        $request->file('image')->move(
            $image_path, $filename
        );
        echo $filename;    
    }
    else{
        echo 'Oh No! Uploading your image has failed.';
    }
}
```

I'm using the most recent master version of Summernote and here's the list of things I've tried so far:

1. [Found a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30578916/summernote-show-images-that-have-been-uploaded-to-a-folder) and tried what it says but no luck.
2. Visited [Summote API documentation](http://summernote.org/#/deep-dive#callbacks) and tried '$summernote.summernote('insertNode', imgNode);'  but only gets error - complaning 'TypeError: a.nodeName is undefined'.
3. Well, My codes are based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628222/summernote-image-upload) but 'editor.insertImage(welEditable, url);' is already deprecated so not useful anymore.
4. Tried the following codes based on #2. Basically trying to see if images from other websites can be added - assuming my image path is wrong. But not working.

   //Full path?

   $('#summernote').summernote("insertImage", 'http://animalia-life.com/data_images/fish/fish1.jpg');

   //If not, full path with 'filename' option?

   $('#summernote').summernote("insertImage", 'http://animalia-life.com/data_images/fish/fish1.jpg','filename');

   //If not, path + filename?

   $('#summernote').summernote("insertImage", 'http://animalia-life.com/data_images/fish','fish1.jpg');

   //If not, path + /  ?

   $('#summernote').summernote("insertImage", 'http://animalia-life.com/data_images/fish/','fish1.jpg');
5. Tried if data image can be added, and **IT WORKS. BUT WHY.**

   //data image?

   $('#summernote').summernote("insertImage", 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZ...blahblah....');

At this point, I learned that **$('#summernote').summernote("insertImage", ... )**  is actually working but the image url parameter is possibly not.  Has anyone successfully implemented this feature with the latest version of Summernote? or... Am I missing something here?

Comment: Here is a good solution i provide you of all you want ....... just go to this link

http://www.somrat.info/summarnote-image-upload-with-laravel/

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out.

base_path()  gives me a physical local path of the uploaded file on my PC. However, this whole thing is running on MAMP. Thus, url has to be something like 'http://localhost:8888/image/......'

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var IMAGE_PATH = 'http://localhost:8000/images/thread/';

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content')     }
});
$('#summernote').summernote({
    height: 400,
    onImageUpload: function(files) {
        data = new FormData();
        data.append("image", files[0]);
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: "POST",
            url: "/image/upload",
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(filename) {
                var file_path = IMAGE_PATH + filename;
                console.log(file_path);
                $('#summernote').summernote("insertImage", file_path);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

});

Comment: You could change the ports on MAMP to the default ports too.